# Ошибка decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python

```
print("Степень числа b:", round(decimal.Decimal(b)**decimal.Decimal(a),4))
```

Выдает ошибку `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`  в строках со степенью. Не могу понять почему. Что мне собственно делать?

```
 a = input("Введите первое число:")      
 b = input("Введите второе число:")      
 time.sleep(5)      
 a = float(a)      
 b = float(b)      
 decimal.getcontext().prec = 100      
 print("Степень числа a:", round(a**b, 4))      
      print("Степень числа b:",round(decimal.Decimal(b)**decimal.Decimal(a),4))
```

Comment: Ну, видимо потому что нельзя применять такую операцию к этому типу данных ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Приведите весь код полностью. Что в `b` и `a`? Скорее всего, там нули.

Comment: Код поместите в вопрос (кнопка "править"). Для каких именно входных параметров получаете ошибку?

Comment: Можете объяснить, что вы имеете в виду под входными параметрами?

Comment: Значения переменных `a` и `b`

Comment: Ошибка может быть получена для обеих переменных, при подходящих условиях.

Comment: Т.е. значения, при которых ошибку можно воспроизвести, вы сообщать категорически не хотите?

Comment: Эти значения неоднозначны, их очень много. Я просто не могу их сообщить все или не знаю как.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы один пример входных данных, на котором у вас возникает такая ошибка.

Comment: Значение b>2000, значение a тоже может быть >2000

Comment: Это огромное число. При таких значениях `a**b` уже должен дать ошибку переполнения.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я хочу это число каким-то образом выразить с помощью decimal